# C#: iterating through DataTable columns of unknown names to check data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I have a `DataTable` populated from an Excel sheet, now the Data needs to be manipulated in terms of what's in that column.

For Example, if `ColumnA` has a combination of numbers 1, 2 and 3, then leave that column untouched, but if `ColumnA` doesn't have that kind of combination this column should be deleted.

Now the problem arises if I use the `dataTable.Select("")` method.
I don't know the column names and how I will achieve this through out all columns and actually apply the where clause across the columns. This manipulation is all based on columns not row.

If anyone has advices or can point me to the right direction please do.

**EDIT**
Below is the code that populates the DataTable with ExcelSheet.

```
ds = new DataSet();
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Excel07ConString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelSchema.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
                oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                oda.Fill(dt);
                dt.TableName = sheetName;
                comboBoxData.Add(sheetName.Replace("$", ""));
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are the columns unnamed because their names are not transported from a header row in Excel, or are you having trouble to obtain them from  `DataTable.Columns`? It may help to show code you've written so far.

Comment: @dlatikay the columns are named, but initially after populating the dataTable I cant tell the names and number of columns. And I dont want to hard-code this names as Excel sheets come in different names and formats. So we need to work on them blindly. I will Edit Question with code.

Comment: does the same set of rules apply to the contents of each column? then it would simply mean to iterate `foreach(var column in dataTable.Columns) { ... }`, and dynamically build your query using the column names from the loop

Comment: @dlatikay yes set of rules apply to all columns.

Comment: ok. the basic idea is clear, just one more thing: when you talk about "a combination of numbers 1, 2, 3", you look for that in the cells? and remove the entire column if: all match / none match / some match?

Comment: @dlatikay yes you look into cells, and remove whole column if they dont match.

Answer (score 1):

First, identify the columns to remove by applying the rules to the data each:

```
var columnsToRemove = new List<DataColumn>();

foreach(var column in dataTable.Columns)
{
    if(BusinessRulesSatisfied(dataTable, column) == false)
    {
        columnsToRemove.Add(column);
    }
}
```

If it is necessary to address columns by name inside the actual implementation of `BusinessRulesSatisfied`, you can do so using `column.ColumnName`.

Then remove the columns found to not match the rules:

```
foreach(var column in columnsToRemove)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Remove(column);
}
```

In this way, the column names are kept out of consideration. Which is recommended because Excel does not have a strict concept of relational tables, permitting empty and duplicate headings.

Comment: This now makes a lot of sense, I see on "BusinessRulesSatisfied" you passing the DataTable and column which I'm okay with, but now the rules I will be applying brings us back to how to Implement the query? Am i missing something? Can we discuss "BusinessRulesSatisfied" further...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively straightforward way to apply your additional row filtering rules on your existing DataTable.  I don't know your ACTUAL filtering rules that need to be applied to each column, so to keep my example simple, I assumed a simple rule of "every column <> 1":

```
string filter = "";
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtExcelSchema.Columns)
{
    if (filter != "")
        filter += " AND ";

    filter += dc.ColumnName + " <> 1";
}

// so at the end, filter will be a string in the form of "ColumnA <> 1 AND ColumnB <> 1 AND ColumnC <> 1" etc
dtExcelSchema.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
```